# How to Transition to (the current) route

Tags: ember.js

In my app I'm able to select a " group" model from anywhere in the app. All groups are loaded into the application's model hook, and then the selectedGroup is saved as a property in the application controller.

A lot of the routes have models that are dependent on the selectedGroup, so when a new group is chosen, I need to reload the current route. From what I've been able to read, the best way to achieve this is to just to transitionToRoute.

Is this the best way to do things? And how do I get the current route, in order to then re - transition to it.

Please comment if further explanation needed! Thanks!

**Edit**

A possible route's code:

```
needs: ['application'],

model: function() {
    var groupID = this.controllerFor('application').get('activeClass.id');
    return this.store.find('student', { group: groupID });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can get the `currentRoute` from the application controller. Since `selectedGroup` is also saved on the application controller, you can add an observer to it and inside that do your transition. The code will look something like.

```
App.ApplicationController = Em.Controller.extend({
  selectedGroup: '',

  onSelectionChange: function() {
    var currentRoute = this.get('currentRouteName');
    this.transitionToRoute(currentRoute);
  }.observes('selectedGroup')
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I thought re - transitioning to the current route would reload the models etc, but it turns out it doesn't! I'm still using your code, but I'm transitioning to application level first, then back to the current route, which then causes models to be loaded correctly. I suppose the other option might be to try and manually pass the model into the transitionTo function. But this works, and seemingly as quickly as I'd imagine the other. Thanks

Comment: Well you could try something like the reload method on the route object, this should trigger the model hooks again.